# Problem with root equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help me solve this equation:

$3\sqrt{2+x}-6\sqrt{2-x}+4\sqrt{4-x^2}=10-3x$

where x is a real number.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Use $\sqrt{4-x^2}=\sqrt{(2-x)(2+x)}$ To control your work: the solution ist $x=\frac 6 5$

Comment: Did you try squaring both sides? It's a bit long but definite way!

Comment: @GregVoit Since there are three radicals, it takes some work, and you need to square both sides twice, with some subtracting of terms in-between. I don't think I would recommend that course of action in this case. Dividing by for instance $\sqrt{2-x}$ is a safer route IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$(\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x})^2=10-3x-4\sqrt{2+x}\sqrt{2-x}$$

---

First note the restrictions on the domain of the function

$$f(x)=3\sqrt{2+x}-6\sqrt{2-x}+4\sqrt{4-x^2}-10+3x.$$

The term $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ requires that $-2\leq x \leq 2$. The restrictions to the domain implied by the other two square-root terms are consistent with this domain and don't restrict it further.

To find the roots of $f(x)$ we set it equal to $0$. Rearranging the resulting equation a little bit, we have to solve:

$$3\left(\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x}\right)=10-3x-4\sqrt{4-x^2}.$$

Using the hint I mentioned above, note that the RHS of the equation is equal to the expression

$$u^2=\left(\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x}\right)^2,$$

where we've defined $u:=\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x}$ for convenience. Rewriting the equation in terms of $u$, it becomes simply:

$$3u=u^2.$$

The roots of this equation are $u=0$ and $u=3$, reducing the main problem to finding the roots of $\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x}=0$ and $\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x}=3$. In the first case,

$$\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x}=0
\implies 2+x=4(2-x)
\implies 2+x=8-4x\\
\implies x=6-4x\\
\implies 5x=6\\
\implies x=\frac65.$$

You can go back to the original equation and verify directly that $x_1=\frac65$ is indeed a root.

As for the other case in which $\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x}=3$, just note that

$$\sqrt{2+x}-2\sqrt{2-x}\leq \sqrt{2+x} \leq 2 <3,$$

from which it follows immediately that no real roots exist for this case.

To summarize, $3\sqrt{2+x}-6\sqrt{2-x}+4\sqrt{4-x^2}-10+3x=0$ has exactly one root:

$$x_1=\frac65.$$

Comment: What next you will do it to solve it?
I found the solution but not like you.
Can you show your solution?

Comment: @phuong I updated my answer to include a full work-up of the problem. You didn't actually solve the problem the long way, did you?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Denote:

$f(x) = 3\sqrt{2+x}-6\sqrt{2-x}$

$g(x) =  10-3x - 4\sqrt{4-x^2}$

f(x) is the increase function.

g(x) increase when $x<\frac{6}{5}$, decrease when $x>\frac{6}{5}$.

the number of solution for f(x) = g(x), not large than 2.

And we also have: $f(\frac{6}{5}) =g(\frac{6}{5})$

Easy to see that $\frac{6}{5}$ is unique solution for f(x) = g(x)